save xml transformation in new xml file
Hej!
I have a xslt file to transform my xml which works perfectly well :)
BUT I only get the results in the terminal in oxygen and not in a separate file.
I tried:
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
xmlns:telota="http://www.telota.de"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

    <xsl:result-document href="new_badius.xml"/>

which gives me the error: "Element xsl:result-document must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet"
tried some variation of hierarchy:
<xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:result-document href="new_file.xml"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

or
<xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:result-document href="new_file.xml"/>
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

which gives me the error only one new_file.xml can be created (which is empty)
Where should I put <xsl:result-document href="new_file.xml"/> or is there a better way to save my outcome as a .xml?

https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/xsl-elements/result-document.html#:~:text=It%20is%20used%20to%20direct%20output%20to%20a%20secondary%20output%20destination. will copy the tree for that template to a new file, it is not the usual way of selecting primary output, which will depend on how you are  or intend to be calling whatever processor you are using in your production environment rather than your XML editor.

The xsl:result-document belongs into a template, which template obviously depends on both your XML input structure, your stylesheet structure and the number and wanted content of the result document(s?).
Assuming you want your complete document to be processed to construct one result tree to be written to one result document you might want e.g.
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="new_file.xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

That then assumes your stylesheet has some meaningful templates to transform the input elements into the wanted output elements.
Also note, that oXygen allows you to configure a transformation scenario where you can define that the primary result is written to a file whose name you can define, see https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/26.1/ug-editor/topics/the-output-tab.html.
If you run Saxon from the command line, use e.g. -o:new_result.xml.
If you run Java code or Python code, see the Saxon documentation about the relevant API documentation.

when I put it inside the templates it creates an empty file.
I don't want anything special, just the output I get from the different xsl:template in one new xml file -> the output in the terminal saved to a file.

@piah, see whether the edit helps, in the end it all depends as to what your existing stylesheet does and which templates it has. See also the note about oXygen allowing you to configure your transformation scenario to create named result file.

From my reading of the question, there is no need to use xsl:result-document at all. Just find the place in the Oxygen Transformation Scenario where you tell Oxygen where to write the output file.
